# Foreach giving one too many list items, how can I remove the last empty line?

Tags: custom-field, list, php

Hello Stackexchange users! I built a simple function to display a list of items from custom fields. However it is listing an empty last field  on the front end and I cant figure out how to remove it. Please help me :)

```
function something_custom_fields() {
    $thumb = get_post_meta($post->ID,'Thumbnail', true);
    $thumb = ( !empty( $thumb ) ) ? $thumb : get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/icon_something.png';
$checkmark = get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/icon_check.png';
    $lista = genesis_get_custom_field('_something_field_type', $post->ID);
if(empty($lista)) {  return false; }
else {
print '<div id="something_custom_fields"><img src="' . $thumb . '" alt="something" /><ul><h2>List Header</h2>';
foreach ( $lista as $key => $value ) { 
echo '<li>' . $value . '<img src="' . $checkmark . '" alt="Post Thumb" class="fitness-checkmark" /></li></ul>';

if(empty($value) ){ 
            return false; }
}
}
echo '</div>';
}
```

[image: Adds one too many list lines]

Comment: What is the value of `$lista` variable (could you `var_dump` it and show us the content)? What should be the output (your foreach loop doesn't print enything at all)?

Comment: Your current code doesn't make much sense (to me). I'm pretty sure, you don't want to `return` inside the foreach, you want to `continue` or something like that. And what is `echo("")`? This doesn't make any sense either. And where do you actually generate the list items, and close the list (`</ul>`)?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż This is the content it's printing. As you can see there is string(0) without any content but its still appearing in the list. 

I corrected echo ("") into return false. I may place some information here if my loop does not return any values. 

string(9) "Treadmill" 
string(12) "Free Weights" 
string(15) "Rowing Machines"
string(16) "Stairway Machine" 
string(14) "Exercise Bikes" 
string(12) "Leg Machines"
string(3) "TRX" 
string(11) "Power Plate" 
string(0) ""

Comment: Looks like one line of code was missing in my question. I added the line: "echo '<li>' . $value . '<img src="' . $checkmark . '" alt="Post Thumb" class="fitness-checkmark" /></li></ul>';
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find the answer to my problem of empty custom fields showing on the page.

```
/** Get Fitness Custom Fields from listing page **/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'something_custom_fields', 23 );

function something_custom_fields() { 

//Get picture from post meta or template directory
$thumb = get_post_meta($post->ID,'Thumbnail', true); 
$thumb = ( !empty( $thumb ) ) ? $thumb : get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/icon.png'; 

//Get checkmark for after each list item from template directory
$checkmark = get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/check.png'; 

//Define custom fields in this case with Genesis 
$lista = genesis_get_custom_field('_something_field_type', $post->ID); 

// The title of the section
echo '<div id="style_custom_fields"><img src="' . $thumb . '" />
<h2>Title</h2>';

// the rule to display items in foreach loop
if( $lista ) { 
        foreach( $lista as $key => $value ) { 

// if value is nothing the display none
if( $value != '') { 
echo '<li>' . $value . '<img src="' . $checkmark . '" class="checkmark-style" /></li>'; } 
} 
echo '</div>'; 
} 
}
```